# Want to use async functions in recursion javascript

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, quicksort

I'm trying to implement quick sort in javascript and need `await sleep()` inside a function, but when I'm using `async` the function is not getting correct result.

On removing `async` from the `partition` function code is working fine.
Can anyone help?

```js
async function partition(low, high) {
  var pivot = random_numbers[low];  // random_number is a global variable contains 10 random number
  var i = low+1;
  var j = high;

  while (i <= j){
    if (random_numbers[i] < pivot){
        i++;
    }else{
        swap_values(i, j);  // this will swap values in random_numbers
        swap_boxes_sq(i, j);  // this will perform some animation
        await sleep(MAX_SLEEP_TIME); // MAX_SLEEP_TIME = 2000 and sleep is defined in other file
        j--;
    }
  }

  swap_values(low, i-1);      
  return i-1;
}

function sort_q( low, high) {
  if (low < high){
    var pi = partition( low, high);
    sort_q(low, pi-1);
    sort_q(pi+1, high);
  } 
}

function quick_sort(low, high) {
  low = 0;
  high = number_of_box -1;  // number_of_box = 10
  sort_q(low, high);
  console.log(random_numbers);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of `sleep()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You made `partition` asynchronous so you need to add await in `sort_q` (and make it asynchronous), and add await in `quick_sort`

The problem is that `partition` is async, so it returns a Promise. `sort_q` won't get the correct result for `pi` if you don't await the result of this Promise.

```
async function partition(low, high) {
  var pivot = random_numbers[low];  // random_number is a global variable contains 10 random number
  var i = low+1;
  var j = high;

  while (i <= j){
    if (random_numbers[i] < pivot){
        i++;
    }else{
        swap_values(i, j);  // this will swap values in random_numbers
        swap_boxes_sq(i, j);  // this will perform some animation
        await sleep(MAX_SLEEP_TIME); // MAX_SLEEP_TIME = 2000 and sleep is defined in other file
        j--;
    }
  }

  swap_values(low, i-1);      
  return i-1;
}

async function sort_q( low, high) {
  if (low < high){
    var pi = await partition( low, high);
    sort_q(low, pi-1);
    sort_q(pi+1, high);
  } 
}

async function quick_sort(low, high) {
  low = 0;
  high = number_of_box -1;  // number_of_box = 10
  await sort_q(low, high);
  console.log(random_numbers);
}
```